One entity in more than one category, count half in each category
I have stumbled onto a problem I haven't been able to solve. I have a person in two different categories, and I need to count them as 0.5 in each category.
Here is the sample data:

Notice that ID Number 18 has a slash indicating that the two departments. I need the output to read as follows.

My first thought was to split the DEPT column, but I am not sure where to go from there since the two rows are identical. My code is as follows. Any suggestions?
Grad_Applied_Formatted1 <-  Grad_AppAccMat %>%
separate_wider_delim(DEPT,"/", names= c("DEPT1","DEPT2"), 
too_few = "align_start",cols_remove = F)


We cannot read your screenshot into our R as a data frame. Please provide reproducible data. A simple way is dput(Grad_AppAccMat) and copy/paste the output to your post.

The key is to group by ID and use row_number(). One approach is mutate(df,DEPT=stringr::word(DEPT,row_number(),sep = fixed("/")),.by=ID). You can use the same logic for separate_wider_delim.

Using strsplit with row_number
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(DEPT = strsplit(DEPT, "/")[[1]][row_number()], .by = ID)
   ID DEPT COUNT
1   1  BIO   1.0
2   2  EDU   1.0
3   3 PHYS   1.0
4   4  MAR   1.0
5   5  SPA   1.0
6   6  FRE   1.0
7   7  KWL   1.0
8   8  QED   1.0
9   9  XYZ   1.0
10 10  UNI   1.0
11 11  RED   1.0
12 12  KJH   1.0
13 13  LMS   1.0
14 14  OPU   1.0
15 15  RTY   1.0
16 16  GHF   1.0
17 17  VZX   1.0
18 18  EPI   0.5
19 18  ENH   0.5

Or a base R approach
transform(df, DEPT = unlist(sapply(split(df, df$ID), \(x) {
                              res <- strsplit(x$DEPT, "/")
                              unlist(res)[seq_len(length(res))]})))
   ID DEPT COUNT
1   1  BIO   1.0
2   2  EDU   1.0
3   3 PHYS   1.0
4   4  MAR   1.0
5   5  SPA   1.0
6   6  FRE   1.0
7   7  KWL   1.0
8   8  QED   1.0
9   9  XYZ   1.0
10 10  UNI   1.0
11 11  RED   1.0
12 12  KJH   1.0
13 13  LMS   1.0
14 14  OPU   1.0
15 15  RTY   1.0
16 16  GHF   1.0
17 17  VZX   1.0
18 18  EPI   0.5
19 18  ENH   0.5

Data
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L,
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 18L), DEPT = c("BIO",
"EDU", "PHYS", "MAR", "SPA", "FRE", "KWL", "QED", "XYZ", "UNI",
"RED", "KJH", "LMS", "OPU", "RTY", "GHF", "VZX", "EPI/ENH", "EPI/ENH"
), COUNT = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 0.5, 0.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))


I would first split the rows on / (making them distinct before) and then simply calculate 1 / n for the count:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
(sample_df <- tibble(ID = c(1:3, 3), DEPT = c(LETTERS[1:2], rep("D/E", 2L))))

# # A tibble: 4 × 2
#      ID DEPT 
#   <dbl> <chr>
# 1     1 A    
# 2     2 B    
# 3     3 D/E  
# 4     3 D/E

sample_df %>%
  distinct() %>%
  separate_rows(DEPT, sep = "/") %>%
  mutate(COUNT = 1 / n(), .by = ID)

# # A tibble: 4 × 3
#      ID DEPT  COUNT
#   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
# 1     1 A       1  
# 2     2 B       1  
# 3     3 D       0.5
# 4     3 E       0.5


You can use tidyr::separate_longer_delim() and then remove duplicated rows.
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(17, 18, 18),
  DEPT = c("VZX", "EPI/ENH", "EPI/ENH"),
  COUNT = c(1, 0.5, 0.5)
)

df %>%
  tidyr::separate_longer_delim(DEPT, delim = '/') %>%
  dplyr::distinct()

#   ID DEPT COUNT
# 1 17  VZX   1.0
# 2 18  EPI   0.5
# 3 18  ENH   0.5


Doing tapply() with a strsplit()-construct if needed. The idea assumes the real data is as well organised as the toy data given.
tapply(df[-1], list(ID= df$ID), \(x) if(nrow(x)==2) 
  transform(x, DEPT = strsplit(x[1, "DEPT"], "/")[[1]]) else x) |>
  array2DF() |> `row.names<-`(NULL) # cosmectics

giving
   ID DEPT COUNT
1   1  BIO   1.0
2   2  EDU   1.0
3   3 PHYS   1.0
4   4  MAR   1.0
5   5  SPA   1.0
6   6  FRE   1.0
7   7  KWL   1.0
8   8  QED   1.0
9   9  XYZ   1.0
10 10  UNI   1.0
11 11  RED   1.0
12 12  KJH   1.0
13 13  LMS   1.0
14 14  OPU   1.0
15 15  RTY   1.0
16 16  GHF   1.0
17 17  VZX   1.0
18 18  EPI   0.5
19 18  ENH   0.5

